# PHP output hex string "as is"

Tags: php, sql-server

I am having a weird problem and have hit a road block.

**Background:**

I am working with MSSQL database.

The table that I am querying has a "**TIMESTAMP**" field.

**Problem:**

When I try to output the data retrieved from this column, I get weird output.

For example, suppose I have the following data saved in the field:
0x000000000ADDAB2F

PHP will output it as:
������

Perhaps it is happening because PHP is trying to convert this string to a number or something.

What I want to do is output the string "AS IS" (i.e I dont want PHP to process it at all, just output the raw data).

I am unable to find a solution that will stop PHP from processing this data.

I am using **mssql_*** functions to query the data.

**What I have tried**

As I dont even have a clue of why is it happening at all, I tried to implement whatever I could find on the Google. So far I have tried to convert the number back to its original form.

So I have used `utf8_decode`, `mb_encode_numericentity`, `mb_decode_numericentity`, `base_convert`, `unpack` and `dechex`

None of them do what I am trying to do.

If you are going to suggest converting the TIMESTAMP value to NVARCHAR or something in the SQL Query itself, then please note that this is not possible.

Because I am creating a simple generic query form, where a user will type MSSQL queries in a textarea and will get the results returned in the browser.

So he can type SELECT * FROM table and he should get all columns in the output.

So it is not possible to fix the problem in the query itself, I have to do it in PHP itself.

Any help?

Comment: Outputing ������ means that data are Raw. If you want to display 0x000000000ADDAB2F, you need to execute [dechex](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.dechex.php) function first (EDIT : As kainaw says, bindec is the good way after all)

Comment: Use bin2hex. What PHP is printing is the actual binary value. The 0x.... that you see is a hex representation of the binary data.

Comment: In SQL you can use `SELECT CAST(... AS VARBINARY(MAX))`. In PHP you have `bin2hex()`.

Comment: @kainaw bin2hex did the job! thank you!, please right it as an answer so that I can mark it as accepted!. just a side question, is there a way to determine if I have got a value that needs to be output using bin2hex?

Comment: You may be needing to have a look on the unpack function of php, if your SQL server does not have a conversion function implemented. http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php

Comment: Do you mean figure out if a column is binary? That depends on the PHP library you are using.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes, please explain

Comment: I am using mssql_* functions to talk to SQL server (I mentioned that in the question). It has a function `mssql_field_type` but that functions returns `BLOB` for `TIMESTAMP` columns, which is... not very helpful. Or may be I should just use bin2hex on all BLOB fields?

Comment: Sorry, I had overlooked that. `BLOB` means "Binary Large Object".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bin2hex. What PHP is printing is the actual binary value. The 0x.... that you see is a hex representation of the binary data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

An SQLServer `TIMESTAMP` value is a number but, for some reason, PHP stores it as string. A string is just a sequence of bytes. When these bytes are interpreted as characters, some of them might not be printable.

There are several ways to convert the sequence of bytes in something you can use further (for printing, computation etc).

If you need the value as number then you can use [`unpack()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php).

Assuming the raw value you get from the database is stored in the `$rawData` variable, the following code should display `0x000000000ADDAB2F`:

```
$values = unpack('J', $rawData);
printf('0x%016X', $value[1]);
```

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thank you for the explanation. I didn't remember that, didn't work with SQL Server from long time ago.

Comment: I removed my comment about `TIMESTAMP` not being an actual date because I realised I wasn't fully sure and I don't want to spread more misinformation. But I'm kind of sure it isn't. In fact it's an alias for `ROWVERSION`.

Comment: No problem. Let's take a look to the documentation: [*"`rowversion` is a data type that exposes automatically generated, unique binary numbers within a database. `rowversion` is generally used as a mechanism for version-stamping table rows. The storage size is 8 bytes. The `rowversion` data type is just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time. ... `timestamp` is the synonym for the `rowversion` data type."*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.130).aspx) -- You are right.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print/show any hex value from a variable, You can use the code below:

```
$hex_value=0x000000000ADDAB2F;
echo sprintf("0x%'016X", $hex_value);
```